# VBA to rename sheets from active sheet sequentially

Tags: vba

Its been a long time.  I need a VBA to name my sheets Test 1, Test 2 etc from the active sheet and all to the right.

OR do the same for all selected sheets.  IE, I'd select a block of 10 sheets and run my macro to rename them "Test 1,...Test 10"
it doesn't matter which method but there are sheets that I don't want the names changed so I either need the following to work ONLY  on a block of selected sheets OR from an active sheet and all to the right.

I'm working from the following code:

```
Sub nameShts()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Name = "Week" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You have 3 solutions below. If they work, please accept the solution that tickles your fancy the most, which will benefit both you and the volunteers!

Answer (score 3):

You were close for idea to loop from selected sheet to last sheet. Instead of `1 to Worksheets.Count` use `ActiveSheet.Index to Worksheets.Count`

---

```
Sub nameShts()

Dim i As Integer

For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Name = "Week" & i
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

To loop the selected sheets, use `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets` to get a collection of the selected sheets.

Then simply loop the collection.

Select your desired sheets and run this:

```
Sub nameShts()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
        sh.Name = "Week" & i
        i = i + 1
    Next sh
End Sub
```

It will only change the sheets selected

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet.Next` seems like a good fit for this problem

```
Sub nameShts()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Do
        ws.Name = "Test " & (ws.Index - ActiveSheet.Index + 1)
        Set ws = ws.Next
    Loop While Not ws Is Nothing
End Sub
```